# Application not showing up in Azure security center

Tags: azure, web-applications

I am working with Azure and I created a Virtual network to start off.I then added a VM and a web application to it successfully. However, when checking my security center, it shows the health of my VM and network but not my application([security center image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJFT7.png)).

Am I possibly forgetting to connect something properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure, are you expecting Azure Security Center to somehow monitor application inside your VM?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Security Center do cover web applications that run on VMs.

Make sure you enable access to your VMs using port 80/443 in your NSG:

> According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/security-center-policies):
>
> > Web application firewall - Recommends that a web application firewall be provisioned on virtual machines when either of the following is true:
> >     Instance-level public IP (ILPIP) is used and the inbound security rules for the associated network security group are configured to allow access to port 80/443.